# Get float values from strings

Tags: python, text, blender

I want to make an object-encoder in Blender with Python that is reading the values (coordinates) from a textdocument, structured like so:

```
p(-9,-8,27)
p(-9,-23,27) 
p(-7,-24,63) 
p(-7,-11,63)
```

How I can make the `'p('` and `')'` disappear in the code so that the `int` convertion is successful?

I have written so far:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    words = line.split('(')
    if len(words) == 0 or words[0].startswith('/'):
        pass
    elif words[0] == 'p':
        words[0].replace('p','')
        words[1].replace(')','')
        pos = words[0].split(',')
        print(pos)
        x, y, z = float(pos[0]), float(pos[1]), float(pos[2])
        mesh.verts.append(Blender.NMesh.Vert(x, y, z))
        print(x, y, z)
```

The error I get:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'p'
```

Comment: regex would be better suited for this

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace()` returns a *new* string object with the replacements made; the `words` values are not affected.

I'd use `str.strip()` to remove the `p` and parentheses from the line:

```
for line in file:
    if not line.startswith('p'):
        continue  # skip these lines
    words = line.strip('\np()').split(',')
    x, y, z = map(float, words)
    mesh.verts.append(Blender.NMesh.Vert(x, y, z))
```

Here we skip any lines without a `p` at the start, and `str.strip()` removes any of the characters found in the argument from the start and end of a string; so any `p`, `(` and `)` characters from both the start and end are removed (as well as newlines, which are always present when reading lines from a file):

```
>>> 'p(-7,-24,63)\n'.strip('\np()')
'-7,-24,63'
>>> 'p(-7,-24,63)\n'.strip('\np()').split(',')
['-7', '-24', '63']
>>> x, y, z = map(float, 'p(-7,-24,63)\n'.strip('\np()').split(','))
>>> x, y, z
(-7.0, -24.0, 63.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This will only run when all lines contain coordinates. Sorry for unprecise asking. How can the script skip the line if there arent any 'p's as a starting character?         **if not words or not words[0].startswith('p'):
            continue  # skip this line**    don't work. And may I ask why there are 2 Arrays in your words? Thanks

Comment: @McMidas: sorry, my mistake; a split with an explicit argument always results in a string (even an empty one); corrected. `words` is a list of strings; strings can be indexed too. So `words[0][0]` is the first element (a string), first character.

Comment: alright, understood this. But now `if not words or not words[0][0] == 'p':` don't work, there is a IndexError: `string index out of range`

Comment: @McMidas: if you want to check for a `p`, then do so *before* stripping; `if not words.startswith('p'): continue` as the first line would do that, for example.

Comment: Did you ment so: `with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
 for line in file: if not words or not words[0][0] == 'p':
   continue  # skip this line
  words = line.strip('\np()').split(',')
  print(words)` But youre calling 'words' before its declarated .

Comment: Sorry, no, that was my mistake; I meant to test against `line` there: `if not line.startswith('p'): continue`

Comment: Thanks. Now by printing it shows me all coordinates. But when I add `mesh.verts.append(Blender.NMesh.Vert(x, y, z))` after the map(float...-part they are not added in Blender.

Comment: @McMidas: I have no experience with Blender here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it always starts with p( and ends with ), you can do it like this:

```
for line in file:
    coords = [float(c) for c in line.strip()[2:-1].split(',')]
    mesh.verts.append(Blender.NMesh.Vert(*coords))
```

line[2:-1] is slicing notation that skips the first 2 characters and the last one as well (so that `"(p(x,y,z)"` becomes `"x,y,z"`). Then, it is split() to get an array of strings `["x", "y", "z"]`. Then, "for each coordinate in that array, give me a float(coordinate)" would be an english translation of "float(c) for c in line..."

Comment: But take into account there *may* be a newline (the last line does not always have the newline at the end, all other lines will have it).

Comment: @Joe could you explain what the `for c in line[2:-1]` - part does? I get an error that the script can not convert the string to float because there is still a `)` at the end.

Comment: @McMidas I added additional explanations to the post. Your error means that the `)` is not removed by `[:-1]` as it should, because there are extra characters in the line. Martijn's answer takes care of this by removing all p, (, ) and \n from the lines. I have adapted my answer to support it as well (split() without arguments will take care of \n, whitespaces and other weird characters that you're not looking for)